# Interarrival time for Counting process?

Tags: probability, queueing-theory, poisson-distribution

Messages arrive at an interactive message center according to a counting process with the average inter-arrival time of 15 seconds. Choosing a frame size of 5 seconds, compute the probability that during 200 minutes of operation, no more than 750 messages arrive.

so I know:
T = 15 seconds = 1/4 minutes
delta = 5 seconds = 1/12 minutes
t = 200 minutes
lambda = 1/15 seconds 
so need to find P(x<=750)

My question is which formulas should I use?

Comment: The normal approximation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so with which parameters? Sorry I get confused doing the normal approx to poisson/binomial

Comment: I hope someone else will answer soon. I will be out of action for several hours (guests about to arrive).